# Command to update terminal as file is updated

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, cat, nginx

I'm looking for a way to have the access log for my nginx install scroll up the terminal as lines are added to the log. I think I need a command like `cat access.log | diff` but I'm not sure exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tail with `-f`:

```
tail -f access.log
```

From [`man tail`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail):

> -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
>        **output appended data as the file grows;** -f, --follow, and --follow=descriptor are equivalent

Comment: cheers, worked perfectly!